# How to replace %20 with - in url

Tags: php

I am new to php. My problem is that , i want to replace `%20` in my url with `-`

Comment: `url_decode($yourURL)`, it will restore spaces and special chars

Comment: how to decode can you show me a expmple code

Comment: @teeyo `%20` is a space, so it will decode to a space, `-` would be `%2D`

Comment: Can you confirm you want `%20` to convert to `-`, rather than a space ?

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: In addition to the other comment above, please clarify if you are changing a URL in the HTML or if you are getting the parameter data from the $_GET scope?

Comment: [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$test1='exmple.com/dp/id/om%20Joan';

$test1=str_replace('%20','-',$test1);
echo $test1;
```

And the output is :

```
exmple.com/dp/id/om-Joan
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$myUrl = 'www.somesite.com/in here/';

$cleanUrl = str_replace('/\\s/', '-', $myUrl);
```

Results:

```
$cleanUrl = 'www.somesite.com/in-here/';
```